# Mock testing exceptions handling

Tags: java, exception, interface, mocking, mockito

**Description:** I want to unit test method that implements interface. Method retrieves data from files, hence potentially throws exceptions. Code that actually retrieves data is `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));` and this piece forces me to handle `IOException`. There are also two other classes that uses interface `FileLinesReader` to retrieve data. Everything works fine, code does what's expected. However when I run the whole code with invalid file name (that doesn't exist in any location), `NoSuchFileException` is thrown which in my understanding is thrown by `Paths.get(fileName)`. I want to properly handle exceptions which can most likely occur during code execution.

**Code:**

```
public interface FileLinesReader {
    List<String> readAllLines(String fileName);
}
```

```
    public class DefaultFileLinesReader implements FileLinesReader {
    String defaultFile;

    public DefaultFileLinesReader(String defaultFile) {
        this.defaultFile = defaultFile;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> readAllLines(String fileName) {
        List<String> linesOutput;

        try {
            linesOutput = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Provided file: \"" + fileName + "\" does not exist. Default file: " + defaultFile);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Do you want to use default file? [y/n]");

            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                while(true) {
                    String input = userInput(scanner);
                    if (input.equals("y")) {
                        try {
                            linesOutput = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(defaultFile));
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Default file not defined!", ex); //Should never be thrown. Default file must exist in MessageSender folder.
                        }
                    }
                    //Default file must exist in designated folder.
                    //If no file selected, execution is ceased.
                    if (input.equals("n")) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("No file selected."); 
                    }
                    System.out.println("Invalid command.");
                    System.out.println("Do you want to use default file? [y/n]");
                }
            }
        }
        return linesOutput;
    }

    //Created to define input in unit tests
    protected String userInput(Scanner scanner) {
        return scanner.next();
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I want to use Mockito to test this class but apparently I still don't understand mocking enough. I want to spy method for setting up user input, and then also by spying throw `RuntimeException` as I would like to cease code execution. What I get in result is like my code is executing normally, not as a test. `try-catch` block is executed but message I get is that `NoSuchFileException` has been thrown. It reaches to the moment when user can enter command, but spying method that should pass "n" as input definitely doesn't work. This is where I get really confused. I'm not sure if I catch exceptions correctly. I've tried to create separate method only for `Paths.get(fileName)` so I could mock it too but I got a feeling that code get's more cumbersome because of it. What I have now is code like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DefaultFileLinesReaderTest {

    private static final String FAKE_FILE = "fakeFile";

    private DefaultFileLinesReader defaultFileLinesReaderTest;
    private DefaultFileLinesReader defFileLinesReaderSpy;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        defaultFileLinesReaderTest = new DefaultFileLinesReader(FAKE_FILE);
        defFileLinesReaderSpy = spy(defaultFileLinesReaderTest);
    }

    @Test
    void readAllLines_RuntimeException() {
        Scanner scanner = mock(Scanner.class);
        when(defFileLinesReaderSpy.userInput(scanner)).thenReturn("n");
        when(defFileLinesReaderSpy.readAllLines(FAKE_FILE)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> defFileLinesReaderSpy.readAllLines(FAKE_FILE));
    }
}
```

And the output when running test is like this:

```
Provided file: "fakeFile" does not exist. Default file: fakeFile
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: fakeFile
    \\stacktrace here
Do you want to use default file? [y/n]
```

**Question:** How can I test if exceptions thrown in `readAllLines` method are handled as I expected?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would throw a subclass of **RuntimeException**, you may think of using **IllegalArgumetException**.

For unit tests, you should have test methods to test the normal behavior of your class method and other test methods for testing thrown exceptions cases.

To test the cases, where an exception might be thrown, you can consider this example (*JUnit 4*):

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void shouldThrowException() {
    exceptionRule.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exceptionRule.expectMessage("Your exception message");
}
```

And if you just want to check the thrown exception type you can simply use :

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void shouldthrowException() {
    // Call method
}
```